# nanoscroller.js - slider/pane not showing in chrome (solution found)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [nanoscroller.js](http://jamesflorentino.github.com/nanoScrollerJS/) to create a scrollable list of things.

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({ alwaysVisible: true });
$(".submenu").addClass("hidden");
```

".submenu" is the parent of ".nano" and only shown after clicking a button.

Everything works fine in FF, Safari and Opera. But in Chrome the slider/pane of the scrollbar don't show up. Has anyone come across the same problem and found a solution to this? Or maybe know an alternative plug-in to create custom scrollbars that can handle this scenario?

#### Edit/Solution:

Found a solution to this:

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({ alwaysVisible: true });
$(".submenu").addClass("hidden");
$(".pane").css("display","block");
$(".slider").css("display","block");
```

manually changing the `display` of `.pane` to `block` seems to do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed. I had the same problem and thanks to this question I solved it. nanoscroller.js is a known jQuery plugin for scrolling tasks. So marking this question as 'too localized' is quite arguable.

Comment: @Greg: Oh, and, protip, if your question is similar but is not answered by the above... *ask it*.  That's why the site exists.

Comment: @Greg: Actually, that is one of the meanings.  If you want to know why, go search for it on meta.SE (not on [meta], the new meta.. ugh, this split sucks).  They keep tweaking close reasons, but you can never have the exact right one for every situation.  TL was used as the close reason for non-questions (in this case, a question self-answered in the body of the question) for a long time.  Now, the close reason would be "Not a Real Question".

Comment: @Will That makes a lot more sense, thanks for clarifying all that.  And I'm sorry about the jerk bit, I've just had a bad couple days...

Comment: Shouldn't the answer-part of the question be converted to a real answer of @motörnerd instead? I don't see why you would want to close this. motörnerd's answer seems like a walkaround, somebody could come up with a better answer.